# Uploading UIImage data to the server getting memory peaks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, memory-pressure

I am trying to upload images data to the server, it uploaded successfully, but getting memory peaks on per image upload. And also uploading more than 20 images getting App shut's down and receiving memory warnings. 
[image: UIImage data memory peaks]

How to resolve this issue?

[image]

**Edit:**
I am using NSURLConnection.

```
 image = [params valueForKey:key];
 partData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([ImageUtility getQualityFilterImage:[params valueForKey:key]], 0.8f);
   if([partData isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
          partData=[((NSString*)partData) dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    [body appendData:partData];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [urlRequest setHTTPBody:body];
```

Comment: You should show us how you're doing the upload. If you use `NSURLSession` upload task with either a file or stream (rather than a `NSData`), you will mitigate this problem. The key is avoid loading the entire asset into memory at any given point in time.

Comment: How you can upload image?can you please put your code here.

Comment: Also, use Instruments allocation tool rather than the gauges in Xcode. It's a far more accurate measure of what's really going on (plus you can see precisely what's causing the growth in memory).

Comment: @NimitParekh Converting UIImage to NSData

Comment: @Vishu please post your code here if possible.

Comment: Hello, Guys, why I am getting negative points in question?

Comment: Because you're asking us how to fix your code but you haven't shared your code with us, despite numerous requests. You have to show us what you're doing (or better, a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Are you using `NSURLConnection`, `NSURLSession`, AFNetworking, etc.? And given the particular technology you're using, how are you using it? Right now, you're just showing us the symptoms of the problem, but not the source of the problem.

Comment: @Vishu make sure your project should be in ARC mode.

Comment: My project is ARC enables?

Comment: Yes, do that first and see 90% memory issues will be solved.

Comment: I mean to say my project has already ARC enabled.

Comment: Okay.. now check the image size which you want to upload. and try to compress that image first and upload that image.

Comment: @Rob I don't want to post all of my code. I think it is not necessary?

Comment: @Vishu No, definitely don't post all of your code. You generally want to post the bare minimum to allow people to reproduce the behavior you describe (see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For now, I think what you provided is adequate for us to at least understand what you're doing (manually building `NSMutableURLRequest` for multipart request).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. If uploading multiple images, you might want to constrain how many you perform concurrently.

   For example, this is my memory when I issued 20 uploads of roughly 5mb per image, memory spiked up to 113 mb:

   [image]

   If, however, I constrained this to only doing no more than 4 at a time (using operation queues), the memory usage was improved, maxing out at 55mb (i.e. roughly 38mb over baseline):

   [image]

   Others have suggested that you might consider not doing more than one upload at a time, and that further reduces the peak memory usage further (in my example, peak memory usage was 27mb, only 10mb over baseline), but recognize that you pay a serious performance penalty for that.
2. If using `NSURLSession`, if you use at upload task with the `fromFile` option rather than loading the asset into a `NSData`, even when doing 4 concurrently it used dramatically less memory, less than 1 mb over baseline:

   [image]
3. I notice that you're using the Xcode gauges to analyze memory usage. I'd suggest using Instruments' Allocations tool (as shown above). The reason I suggest this is not only do I believe it to be more accurate, but more importantly, you seem to have some pattern of memory not falling completely back down to your baseline after performing some actions. This suggests that you might have some leaks. And only Instruments will help you identifying these leaks.

   I'd suggest watching WWDC 2013 video [Fixing Memory Issues](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=410) or WWDC 2012 video [iOS App Performance: Memory](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=242) which illustrate (amongst other things) how to use Instruments to identify memory problems.
4. I notice that you're extracting the `NSData` from the `UIImage` objects. I don't know how you're getting the images, but if they're from your `ALAssetsLibrary` (or if you downloaded them from another resource), you might want to grab the original asset rather than loading it into a `UIImage` and then creating a `NSData` from that. If you use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`, you invariably either (a) make the `NSData` larger than the original asset (making the memory issue worse); or (b) reduce the quality unnecessarily in an effort to make the `NSData` smaller. Plus you strip out much of the meta data.

   If you have to use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` (e.g. it's a programmatically created `UIImage`), then so be it, do what you have to do. But if you have access to the original digital asset (e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27709329/1271826 for `ALAssetsLibrary` example), then do that. Quality may be maximized without making the asset larger than it needs to be.

Bottom line, you first want to make sure that you don't have any memory leaks, and then you want to minimize how much you hold in memory at any given time (not using any `NSData` if you can).

Comment: Thought number 2 reduced my memory usage by a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Memory peaks are harmless. You are going to get them when you are performing heavy uploads and downloads. But it should go back to its normal level later on, which is the case in the image you have posted. So i feel it is harmless and obvious in your case.

You should only worry when your application uses memory and doesnt release it later...

If you are performing heavy upload.. have a look at answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794194/converting-uploading-large-amounts-of-data-from-ipad-to-dropbox).

Comment: but my App shut's down when I am trying to upload more than 20 images?

Comment: Are you sending all of them in one request? If no, I will request you to post our upload code

Comment: Yes, I am sending all of them in one request?

Comment: Are you using NSURLSession?

Comment: No, I don't use NSURLSession?

Comment: Then I would suggest you to switch to NSURLSession. And if possible upload on image at a time. Also check edited answer for a link that will help you in your heavy uploads

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your code ? Have you tried with NSURLSession ? I don't have problems with the memory if I upload photos with NSURLSession.

```
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"SERVER"];

        NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
        for (UIImage *image in self.arrayImages) {
           UIImage *imageToUPload = image;

           NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToUPload);

           NSURLSessionUploadTask *task = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] fromData:data completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

           }];

           [task resume];
        }
```

Comment: It is only for a single file or multiple?

Comment: It is only for a single file, but you can put the code in a bucle